# Typescript : Can we export a function which we have imported in the same file?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

**common-functions-aggregated.ts**

```
import { blank } from './common-some-specific-functions'

export function getTitlePrefix(key) {
    let prefix: string = "";


    return prefix;
}

export blank
```

I am trying to import all the functions from various sources and aggregate and export them from only this **common-functions-aggregated.ts**

How can i achieve this if possible?

Comment: No you have to import class and from class you  need to extract function. Without class object you won't be able to get it.

Comment: thanks for the reply , I'll try with class then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, your syntax was just incorrect:

```
export { blank };
```

Comment: This worked . Your answer was a catalyst for my work .